# objects in arrays- getting values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

As shown in the code below, every 8th day I want to remove the player with the lowest score from the array players and add one from footballStars.
My code removes one football star every 8th day and adds it as an array to the main array of objects. I have tried with Object.assign but still can't retrieve all data at once at the end "tableData5.innerHTML = players.map(playersData)- it displays the name and points of the original content of the player array, but not of the football stars that were added.

```js
var players = [{name: 'Mario', points: 10}, {name:'Marko', points: 8}, {name: 'Andrea', points: 11}, {name: 'Milan', points: 5},{name: 'Matteo', points: 12}, {name: 'Dario', points: 3}, {name: 'Davide', points: 6}, {name:'Darko', points: 16}, {name: 'Fabio', points: 5}, {name: 'Paolo', points: 6}, {name: 'Pablo', points: 7}, {name: 'Goran', points: 13}, {name:'Biaggio', points: 4}, {name: 'Ronaldo', points: 4},{name: 'Andreas', points: 8},{name: 'Paulo', points: 17}, {name: 'Vasco', points: 13}, {name: 'Tino', points: 1}, {name: 'Adriano', points: 6}, {name:'Alessandro', points: 10}, {name: 'Alessio', points: 2}, {name: 'Michele', points: 12}];
    
var footballStars = [{name: 'David', points: 23}, {name: 'Freddie', points: 30}, {name: 'Andrey', points: 24}, {name: 'Cristiano', points: 26}];


var copy = [];

function playersData(item, index) {
  var players2 = [" Player name: " + item.name + ",", " points: " + item.points + " "].join(" ");
  return players2;
}

function getPlayers() {
  var playersD = players.map(playersData);
  console.log(players.map(playersData));
  return playersD;

}
var playersDt = getPlayers();

function getStars() {
  var playersS = footballStars.map(playersData);
  console.log(footballStars.map(playersData));
  return playersS;
}

var playersST = getStars();

var playersPoints = players.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.points - b.points;
});
console.log(playersPoints);


for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
  if (i % 8 === 0) {
    var dismissed = playersPoints.shift();
    console.log("The coach dismissed the player with the lowest score: " + " Player's name: " + dismissed.name + ", points: " + dismissed.points);
    var addStar = footballStars.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * footballStars.length), 1);
    console.log("A football star joined the team: ");
    var addStar2 = Object.assign({}, [addStar.map(playersData)]);
    players.push(addStar2);
    console.log(addStar2);
  }
}

console.log(players);
getStars();
var table = document.createElement("table");
document.body.appendChild(table);
var tableRow5 = document.createElement("tr");
tableRow5.innerHTML = "Changes in team:";
tableRow5.style.backgroundColor = "#afadac";
tableRow5.style.fontSize = "20px";
table.appendChild(tableRow5);
var tableData5 = document.createElement("td");

tableData5.innerHTML = players.map(playersData);

table.appendChild(tableData5);
```

Comment: What, precisely, is the question.

Comment: what can I do to retrieve all players data at the end, ( tableData5.innerHTML = players.map(playersData); ==> this returns updated players array but doesnt display the name and points of the footballStars that were added to the players array.

Comment: Well, `innerHTML` expects actual HTML - you're just passing it an array - you need to loop the array and create the proper html.

Comment: I want to dismiss 1 player(with the lowest score(points) and add 1 footballStar every 8th day, for a period od 30 days.

Comment: This is the part I have a problem with in the innerhtml => Player name: Darko, points: 16 , Player name: Paulo, points: 17 , Player name: undefined, points: undefined , Player name: undefined, points: undefined , Player name: undefined, points: undefined , Player name: undefined, points: undefined

Comment: Players Darko and Paulo are part of the original array, whereas those that have undefined values are the football stars that were added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are trying to achieve. If so, you were on the right track.

Your function `playersData` creates a concatenated string of player information that makes it difficult to parse into a table structure later on in code.

I've removed the use of that below and simplified your code a bit. You'll see that keeping the data structure in-tact allows you to remove and add players just as you had been doing correctly, but it also allows you to build a table.

You'll also note that I adjusted the `for` loop to simply it. Keeping the data structure in-tact allows for pushing the new star directly into the players array.

```js
var players = [{name: 'Mario', points: 10}, {name:'Marko', points: 8}, {name: 'Andrea', points: 11}, {name: 'Milan', points: 5},{name: 'Matteo', points: 12}, {name: 'Dario', points: 3}, {name: 'Davide', points: 6}, {name:'Darko', points: 16}, {name: 'Fabio', points: 5}, {name: 'Paolo', points: 6}, {name: 'Pablo', points: 7}, {name: 'Goran', points: 13}, {name:'Biaggio', points: 4}, {name: 'Ronaldo', points: 4},{name: 'Andreas', points: 8},{name: 'Paulo', points: 17}, {name: 'Vasco', points: 13}, {name: 'Tino', points: 1}, {name: 'Adriano', points: 6}, {name:'Alessandro', points: 10}, {name: 'Alessio', points: 2}, {name: 'Michele', points: 12}];
    
var footballStars = [{name: 'David', points: 23}, {name: 'Freddie', points: 30}, {name: 'Andrey', points: 24}, {name: 'Cristiano', points: 26}];

var playersPoints = players.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.points - b.points;
});

for (var i = 0; i <= players.length; i++) {
  if (i % 8 === 0) {
    var dismissed = playersPoints.shift();
    console.log("The coach dismissed the player with the lowest score: " + " Player's name: " + dismissed.name + ", points: " + dismissed.points);
    var addStar = footballStars.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * footballStars.length), 1)[0];
    console.log("A football star joined the team: ", addStar);
    players.push(addStar);
  }
}

var table = document.createElement("table");
var headerRow = document.createElement("th");
headerRow.style.backgroundColor = "#afadac";
headerRow.style.fontSize = "20px";

Object.keys(players[0]).forEach(key => {
  let headerCol = document.createElement("td");
  headerCol.textContent = key;
  headerRow.appendChild(headerCol);
});
table.appendChild(headerRow);

players.forEach(player => {
  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  Object.keys(player).forEach(key => {
    let col = document.createElement("td");
    col.textContent = player[key];
    row.appendChild(col);
  });
  table.appendChild(row);
});
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: ok, but still i'm not getting the information for the football stars that were added, this is the innerHTML=> Michele 12
Goran 13
Vasco 13
Darko 16
Paulo 17
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]

Comment: @janeDoe000 Sorry for the oversight. It is correct now. The splice was putting the new star into an array. Just pulled that out.

Comment: @janeDoe000 please note as well, that you are sorting your players before adding new ones but not after. If you want them to maintain the sorting order you'll need to sort than after too.

Comment: perfect! Thank u